# "syntax error : missing ';' before '{'" in c++ project with precompiled header

Tags: c++

When trying to compile simple c++ project, I get the following error:

```
syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

I did my research. Compiler doesn't allow declaration of variables inside of a for loop, which is very inconvenient for me.
If I declare loop variables before the for loop, the error disappears.

This is a c++ project with "stdafx.h" precompiled header.

Is this compiler behavior (C89) enforced by the fact that I'm using precompiled header or did I scr**ed something up with my config in the past ?
Is there any way of circumventing this befavior ?

P.S. I'm using visual studio 2012 on windows 7 64-bit;

Code samples:

1. error is on the first line

   ```
   for (int idx = 0, int i = 100; idx < (sizeof(anTestScores) / sizeof(int)); i++, idx++)
   {
       anTestScores[idx] = i;
   }
   ```
2. this compiles

   ```
   int idx;
   int i;
   for (idx = 0, i = 100; idx < (sizeof(anTestScores) / sizeof(int)); i++, idx++)
   {
       anTestScores[idx] = i;
   }
   ```

Comment: What now, do you want C or C++? Do you have .cpp - files? Why do you think C89 is relevant?

Comment: Please show the line that the error is on, as well as a few line before it. You probably made a typo.

Comment: Ivan: C89 and C90 are C Standards. You're claiming to be writing a C++ project. Which is correct?

Comment: Having issues with code formatting on SO... Anyway... yes I'm going through simple c++ tutorial just to try things up before purchasing a book. I would like to compile this project as a c++ project. It is created as a c++ project. It contains only .cpp and header files. I don't bother if it is relevant or not, I would like to not be forced to declare loop variables outside of a loop, it gives me unneeded headache if I have several loops inside of a method or a function. I've found out that this compiler behavior is specific to c89 compiler (if I'm right).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go with

```
for (int idx = 0, i = 100; idx < (sizeof(anTestScores) / sizeof(int)); i++, idx++) { anTestScores[idx] = i; }
```

This declares *two* variables of type int in the first statement of the `for` loop.

The reason this works and your other attempt doesn't is as follows:

Each *declaration* statement has to be separated from each other by a `;`, but the same `;` is used to separate parts of the `for(;;)` loop's header so you tried to get around it by using the ',' operator. Which didn't work due to syntax error

Comment: I was not paying attention, started looking on SO and found the answer by the error message, which led me to think that this issue is related to compiler version. Thank you.